# PHPPowerpoint must display Slide Number

Tags: php

I have a question of using GetSlideNumber and SetSlideNumber in PHPPowerpoint is that the function code to display page number in the every slide? Need help to use that code or proper way in order to display the slide number. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you will be able to get and set page number use following example.

http://phpoffice.github.io/PHPPowerPoint/docs/master/classes/PhpOffice.PhpPowerpoint.Slide.html